# Opening and reading several files in different directories

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I have a huge list of directories. With `/home` as my current directory, the highest level is the year. There are seven years: 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016.

Then there are subdirectories for each month, so for instance `/home/2010/01`. There are, of course, twelve months, each one labeled as 01, 02, 03, ..., 11, 12.

For each month there is each day: 01, 02, ..., with as many days as the month has.

For each day there is a subdirectory always called `0700`. So, following the previous example we would be in `/home/2010/01/01/0700`.

And there is a file in such directory with data (tabular form). The name of the file reveals its date, for instance: `/home/2010/01/01/0700/pnw_20100101_TG.geo`.

I want to read the data in that files and load it to a pandas dataframe to filter outliers. I think I know how to do that, so let's put that apart, but the problem is that I can't read the files. **This is what I have tried**:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home"):
    for name in files:
        f = open(name, 'r')
        f.close
```

But I get the error message associated the opening of the file: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pnw_20100101_TG.geo'.` It seems that it does not recognize the file. But if I do, for instance, `print(os.path.join(root, name))` it correctly lists all the files.

What do you suggest to be able to open and read the files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the simple file name, but in nested folders it will not be found. Join it with the root:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home"):
    for name in files:
        f = open(os.path.join(root, name), 'r')
        f.close
```

Comment: Also you could filter the root folders whether they match your date specification using regular expressions.